# Best practice for conditional output in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm ramping up on ASP.NET MVC and looking at how I output messages in the view.  What's the best way to do something like this?  Helpers?  Controls?  Or just as is?

```
<% if (ViewData.ContainsKey("message") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["message"].ToString())) { %>
    <div class="notice">
        <%= ViewData["message"] %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an html helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string GetMessage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var message = htmlHelper.ViewData["message"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var builder = new TagBuilder("div");
        builder.AddCssClass("notice");
        builder.SetInnerText(message);
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.GetMessage() %>
```

Remark: don't forget to html encode the value of the message if you decide to use your code the way it is.

Comment: Darin,

I like this approach as it would be very 'easy' to always add the <%= Html.GetMessage() %> to any views by default and just 'forget' about it. then the controller logic could decide whether to add anything into the ViewData["message"]. 

now, if only there was a way to easily define the key for the viewdata (other than 'message'), then this would be a nicely self-contained extensible little helper :)

edit - i suppose of course an additional parameter could be added to the helper to define that attribute - or is there a 'better' way??

Answer (score 1):

I think a condition like what you have is the simplest approach. A control feels a bit too "heavy" for this. Maybe a helper method if you find yourself repeating it a lot.